# Calling copy constructor during operator overloading for different operators

Tags: class, constructor, compiler-optimization

This is a relatively simple code which contains an overloaded assignment operator and a multiplication operator. I've returned an object by value for both the operators. What's bugging me is that when I use the assignment operator, the copy constructor is always called while for the multiplication operator, copy constructors are never called.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class foo {
public:
  int x;
  foo() {x=1;}
  foo(int a){x=a;}
  foo(const foo &p){
    cout<<"CC:\tCopying from:  "<<p.x<<'\t'<<&p<<"\tTo:  "<<this<<endl;
  }
  foo operator=(const foo &r){
      cout<<"Assgn:\t"<<"Assigning from:  "<<r.x<<'\t'<<&r
          <<"\tTo:  "<<this->x<<'\t'<<this<<endl;
      return *this;
  }
  foo operator*(const foo &r){
      cout<<"Product:\t"<<"Multiplying from:  "<<r.x<<'\t'<<&r
          <<"\tTo:  "<<this->x<<'\t'<<this<<endl;
      return foo(x*r.x);
  }
};

int main() {
  foo x(1),y(2);
  foo z=x=y;
  foo a=x*y;
  x.x=1; y.x=2;
  x*y*z;
  x=y=z;
  cout<<"X: "<<&x<<endl<<"Y: "<<&y<<endl<<"Z: "<<&z<<endl;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Assgn:  Assigning from:  2  0x7fff2cddbf70  To:  1  0x7fff2cddbf78
CC: Copying from:  1    0x7fff2cddbf78  To:  0x7fff2cddbf68
Product:    Multiplying from:  2    0x7fff2cddbf70  To:  1  0x7fff2cddbf78
Product:    Multiplying from:  2    0x7fff2cddbf70  To:  1  0x7fff2cddbf78
Product:    Multiplying from:  7618584  0x7fff2cddbf68  To:  2  0x7fff2cddbf58
Assgn:  Assigning from:  7618584    0x7fff2cddbf68  To:  2  0x7fff2cddbf70
CC: Copying from:  2    0x7fff2cddbf70  To:  0x7fff2cddbf48
Assgn:  Assigning from:  3  0x7fff2cddbf48  To:  1  0x7fff2cddbf78
CC: Copying from:  1    0x7fff2cddbf78  To:  0x7fff2cddbf40
X: 0x7fff2cddbf78
Y: 0x7fff2cddbf70
Z: 0x7fff2cddbf68
```

The basic thing is, copy constructors are never being called when the multiplication operator is used (not even when i have a statement like foo 'a = x * y'). But while returning the value of 'a = b', copy constructor *is* called.

I know that compiler optimisation makes some changes in the output and that's why CC is not invoked when I declare a variable like `z = x = y` or `z = x * y`. But again, why is CC called when returning x=y when it can directly compute `z` like in the case of `z = x * y`? Is there any specific reason for this? Like, assignment operators are treated differently, or that since I return `*this` in assignment operator, it's different from the case in multiplication operator wherein I return a temporary variable ( this should be unlikely because ASFAIK, the compiler isn't be able to differentiate variables of local and global scope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my assumptions while trying to reach an answer was wrong.

I tried the same thing but just changed the assignment operator definition just a bit so that I first stored the value in a local variable and then returned it. And in this case, no copy constructor was called.

This means that the compiler can and does differentiate between variables of different scopes. Since the code which I posted in the question returns a non-local variable, copy-constructor is called.

I am guessing the same thing would happen (ie CC would be called) when I call the assignment operator from a different function outside the class. Even better yet, it would be interesting to see what happens when CC is called from within a different member function in the same class (although it would probably be the same).